# https domain, try download JS from no-secure http

Tags: javascript, http, ssl, https

I'm have domain on HTTPS, with JS `<script src="http://example.com/some.js?key=cf04b31a52ed4c">` and this script doesn't load. On other domain without SSL, all OK. This problem can resolve if I'm change protocol example.com to HTTPS too or no?

Comment: When you look at the network trace for the page load, what sort of error do you get for that file?

Comment: he page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://example2.com/scripts/track.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use:

```
<script src="///example.com/some.js?key=cf04b31a52ed4c">
```

just in case they provide it also using HTTPS, or check the [Content Security Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy). On recent Chrome and Firefox the developer console should give you a more informed error on whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is confirming your suspicions -- your browser security settings are set to not load unsecured content over a secured connection. Presuming some of your users may have similar settings, it'd be best to serve all of your content over a secured connection as well.